# Gulp not working on windows!? any more?

Tags: node.js, gulp

today I installed gulp with

```
npm -g install gulp
gulp -v
```

and soon appear if I want open a gulp.js file with text editor or dreamweaver, tried on windows 8.1 and 7,

this is the gulpfile, gulpjs

```
var gulp= require('gulp');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');



gulp.task('compress', function() {
  gulp.src('lib/*.js')
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
});
```

clear gulpfile all works well

thanks

Comment: what is your question? it's not readable and what is the problem?

Comment: I have just update, the question is that not works gulp.js script and do nothing...

Comment: "and soon appear if I want open a js file" doesn't make much grammatical sense. What is the actual problem? What command are you using to have the problem? What is the error message (if any) are you getting? What is the Question?

Comment: Why do the two `gulp.dest()` differ? Seems shady. `script` and `compress` do drastically different things. Wouldn't you want them to work together? As it stands compress will uglify each JS file one at a time outputing one minified output per file. I don't think that is what you want is it?

Comment: Your missing a `require('gulp')` is that the entire file?

Comment: no ... the problem is not there, you can erase script task but the problen's still there when i run gulp text file of gulp.js is open...

Comment: added but same issue... now I change the example file

Comment: Do you have gulp and the gulp modules installed locally for the project with `package.json`, `npm install`?

Comment: in global not in local folder

Comment: thanks for dude have signed -1

Comment: gulp needs to be installed in the project as well as global. Also you still have not explained *what the problem is*. "It doesn't work" is not enough to help anyone.

Comment: Answer already provided here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30128092/gulp-command-opens-gulp-js-in-notepad-instead-of-running-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I delete nodejs and node plugins,

then I reinstall node, with bower and gulp globally, other plugin such as gulp-concat etc. use --save-dev this works for windows 8.1

thanks for all people comments