# Gulp command opens gulp.js in notepad instead of running it

Tags: javascript, windows, node.js, command-line, gulp

I installed it correctly I think.

My package.json

```
   {
      "name": "my-project",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "devDependencies": {
        "gulp": "^3.8.11",
        "gulp-concat": "^2.5.2"
      }
    }
```

my gulp.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

    var concat = require('gulp-concat');

    gulp.task('scripts', function() {
        return gulp.src('js/*.js')
          .pipe(concat('main.js'))
          .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js'));
    });

    gulp.task('default', ['scripts']);
```

my folder are as follow :

```
ROOT/package.json
ROOT/gulp.js
ROOT/node-modules/   <-- my modules are here
ROOT/js/  <-- my js are here
```

When I run `gulp` in command line, being in the ROOT folder, gulp.js just opens in windows notepad and that's all..

Why is it doing that?

Comment: Sounds like Windows does not know the Nodejs binary to execute it. What does `node.bat gulp` do?

Comment: it doesnt recognize that command

Comment: node is installed though,`node -v` gives v0.12.2

Answer (score 27, accepted):

problem solved by a simple action: renaming gulp.js to gulpfile.js (sigh..)

Comment: LOL, me too. appends to the bests obviously :)

Answer (score 2):

Two steps:
Step-1) renaming **gulp.js** to **gulpfile.js** as exposed in answer above; Step-2) using  **npm install -g gulp-cli**